# Django Questionnaire app

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I guys I am very new to Django and app dev and I am having trouble to structure my app.

I am creating an app to send team questionaire.So wokflow is the following:

1) I create a team_project (Team_name)

2) Send Invitations to team members using Emails

3) Based on that invitation Team_member signIn (creating a new user) and are directly assigned to that team created.

I have no idea how to handle that and especially part 3
If you could give me a direction how to do it I will really appreciate

Thx you very much

Comment: Well, show what you have done and attempted so far and someone will be glad to help

Comment: in my opinion you could optimize that workflow. It would be clever to directly create a user when you send out the mail and use the email as login name. In the user creation process you can assign them to a Django Group. Like `user = User.objects.create_user('whateverName' use_variable_as_email, 'somePassword')
  g = Group.objects.get(name='Team1') 
  g.user_set.add(user)`

I can write you a proper answer if you want but please edit your question and provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a common requirement, so perhaps there is already a library or solution for it.

to write the code from scratch, which is not recommended, 
You can define a custom url , like example.com/join_team/some_random_looking_unique_string/

create a model which keeps a random string, email , and maybe some kind of expiration policy. Read the unique string in your view, and retrieve the record associated with it. send a form to get more details like password and etc and save the user in database.

I also found this repo that I think does what you want:

https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations

explain more in your question, and you can get more detailed answers!